# What is the default size of JFace wizard? How to know it?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, wizard

I coded the following wizard:

```
package try_eclipsewizardlayout_02;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITableLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class TryWizard extends Wizard {

    abstract class TableLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
    }

    public class Page1 extends WizardPage {

        protected Page1() {
            super("Page 1");
        }

        @Override
        public void createControl(Composite parent) {

            Composite control = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE) {
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return super.toString() + ": control of Page1";
                }
            };
            control.setLayout(new FillLayout());



            Button button = new Button(control, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("Option 1");


            setControl(control);


        }

    }



    Page1 page1 = new Page1();

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        addPage(page1);

    //  getShell().setSize(640, 480);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I appears with some size. Which this size is? How to know it? It can't be the size of largest control, because it is a button and apparently grown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum size of the wizard page is set in the `WizardDialog` which shows the wizard.

The default value is 300 x 225 pixels. `WizardDialog` has a `setMinimumPageSize` method to change this which is used by a lot of Eclipse wizards.